# Simple MVVM with KVO

Tags: swift, mvvm, key-value-observing

I'm trying to create a simple mvvm model using kvo

My goal is when the UITextField text changes, automatically change the UILabel text.
But for some reason the `observeValue` function is not called

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var viewModel : TestViewModel?
    @IBOutlet weak var LBLABEL: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewModel = TestViewModel()

        addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(viewModel.infoText), options:  [.old, .new], context: nil)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        viewModel?.infoText = textField.text
        return true
    }


    // MARK: - Key-Value Observing
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "info" {
            // Update Time Label
            LBLABEL.text = viewModel?.infoText
        }
    }

}


class TestViewModel : NSObject{
    var model : TestModel

    var infoText:String? {
        didSet{
            model.info = self.infoText

        }
    }

    override init() {
        model = TestModel()
    }
}


class TestModel {
    var info:String?
}
```

I already tried to change the observer's declaration or even the ViewModel gets and sets and never succeeded

Comment: Have you added `textField.delegate = self` somewhere in your code?

Comment: @Ahmad F  - yes. in the storyboard. I have put some break points on `shouldChangeCharactersIn` and the code stopped there. the value of the strings in the model and viewmodel are changed correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

According to Apple docs, creating an observer for the key path will be much simpler in Swift 4.

```
class MyObserver: NSObject {
    @objc var objectToObserve: MyObjectToObserve
    var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?

    init(object: MyObjectToObserve) {
        objectToObserve = object
        super.init()

        observation = observe(\.objectToObserve.myDate) { object, change in
            print("Observed a change to \(object.objectToObserve).myDate, updated to: \(object.objectToObserve.myDate)")
        }
    }
}

let observed = MyObjectToObserve()
let observer = MyObserver(object: observed)

observed.updateDate()
```

---

You need to add `dynamic` to the properties of `NSObject` subclass you want to observe. In your case:

```
@objc dynamic var infoText:String? {
    didSet{
        model.info = self.infoText            
    }
}
```

Btw, I don't know why you want to you textField:shouldChangeCharactersIn as it gets the textfield value before updated. Also, `keyPath == "info"` won't never be true. Shouldn't it be something else. E.g., `keyPath == "viewModel.infoText"`?